# Avro schema with the java lang Object type as datatype

Tags: java, serialization, avro

I am learning avro schemas and i tried to make a little project. It seems i am stuck. I tried looking on documentation also but it seems confusing a lot.

Let's assume I have to make a schema for this class

```
class example implements Serializable {
private Object data;
}
```

What would be the corresponding avro schema(.avsc) for it?

I used reflect to get schema and got the corresponding avsc for it but when you do mvn compile, it just throws errors

Comment: it would be helpful get the result schema and the errors on mvn compile, almost sure this is not supported however there are some workarounds for it

Comment: what do you suggest me to do it because this is not some extreme case.

Comment: start by adding your schema result using reflection and the error on compile.  If your object is serializable, you can always create a byte [] array in your schema to handle it

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "type": "record",
    "name": "example",
    "fields": [{
            "name": "x1",
            "type": {
                "type": "map",
                "values": {
                    "type": "record",
                    "name": "Object",
                    "namespace": "java.lang",
                    "fields": []
                }
            }
        }, {
            "name": "data",
            "type": "java.lang.Object"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It's correct for class declaration as follows:
 public class example implements Serializable {
  private Map<String, Object> x1;
  private Object data;
 }
Pay attention taht we don't use Private but private in java.

Comment: Do you have your sources on Github?

Comment: you generated this schema through reflect api right ? this this wont compile , if you try to

Comment: Ok. This is class to be serialized:

 import java.io.Serializable;
 import java.util.Map;

 public class example implements Serializable {
  private Map<String, Object> x1;
  private Object data;

  public example(Map<String, Object> x1, Object data) {
   this.x1 = x1;
   this.data = data;
  }
 }

Comment: import org.apache.avro.Schema;
 import org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter;
 import org.apache.avro.io.DatumWriter;
 import org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData;
 import org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Map;

Comment: public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   String fileName = "c:\\temp\\schema.txt";
   File file = new File(fileName);
   DatumWriter<example> writer = new ReflectDatumWriter<example>(example.class);
   DataFileWriter<example> dataFileWriter = new DataFileWriter<example>(writer);
   Schema schema = ReflectData.get().getSchema(example.class);
   dataFileWriter.create(schema, file);

Comment: Map<String, Object> x1 = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   x1.put("key1","value1");
   x1.put("key2","value2");
   Object object = "someObject";
   dataFileWriter.append(new example(x1, object));
   dataFileWriter.close();
  }
 }

Comment: Sorry for chunks of code but I cannot paste the whole code at once.

Comment: yeah but when you compile this , it will give error

Comment: Object class will give you compilation error in the compile time

Comment: Object? Strange. Object is base type for all Java object types.